# Spring OAuth2 refresh token leave old access token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I create authentication server and it's working good, the problem is when I want to refresh access token the old access token is left in DB and in log there is  **Failed to find access token for token**

Steps are following: 
I call `POST /oauth/token` with `grand_type=refresh_token` and `refresh_token=ACTUAL_TOKEN` and in response I get new refresh token instead of old one and new access token have reference to not existing refresh token.
So if I try to call again refresh with new refresh token I get error that token is not valid but with old one I get new access token but **old token is still in DB**

I still don't have right to embed image so here is the links of db status after login and after first refresh.

[After login DB status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txDf1.png)
[After first refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhYKU.png)

Configuration is like this so it should use old refresh token:

```java
@Bean
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(final TokenStore tokenStore,
                                              final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
        return tokenServices;
    }
```

And looks like refresh_token is changed in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter#enhance`  inside this `if` statement since before if is correct refresh token

```java
DefaultOAuth2RefreshToken token = new DefaultOAuth2RefreshToken(  
      encode(encodedRefreshToken, authentication));  
if (refreshToken instanceof ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken) {  
   Date expiration = ((ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken) refreshToken).getExpiration();  
  encodedRefreshToken.setExpiration(expiration);  
  token = new DefaultExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken(encode(encodedRefreshToken, authentication), expiration);  
}  
result.setRefreshToken(token);
```

At the end I have full db of old access_tokens.